# ASP Classic application based on VB script doesnt display the proper output in IE browser

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, iso-8859-1

I have no knowledge of ASP Classic at all. we have an application running in ASP Classic. There are many pages which ends with .asp extension. but the 2 pages out of it doesn't display in browser the way it should be. all other pages displays well.

The page called reports.asp will give details of over all reports. it used to be working fine and now it is suddenly broken i don't know when it was broken.
here is the block of code on that page. :

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=91042bbe021e2dd7#cid=91042BBE021E2DD7&id=91042BBE021E2DD7%21136

The result display is like this :

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=91042bbe021e2dd7#cid=91042BBE021E2DD7&id=91042BBE021E2DD7%21181

It should look  in table format

Any help to display the file as shown above is really appreciated.

let me know t how to debug this page.
thanks in advance

Nik

Comment: What is the 'block of code'? Something must have changed, have you moved some folders on the server? Have you tried restarting the server where this is running?

Comment: i tried to copy the code but doesn't bring the code instead it shows the output result of HTML. that's the reason i put on the sky drive. with the above link. Also this is the first time i m asking question so i cant put more than 2 hyperlink and i cant insert image into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your asp code and on first glance see nothing wrong but you should open it in a browser with a debugging feature like firefox with the firebug plugin, make the plugin active/viable and switch tot the console window. There errors should be listed with the lines where they occur.

If you have nothing changed at the source and it used to work chances are the problem is in the database or the representation of the data in your code, special characters, regional settings for displaying dates etc.

Comment: In IE Developer tools it doesn't show anything in the head of Html.
The style sheet and logo is not accessible. while on other pages everything is working fine.

Comment: i am able to get the table by recreating a new page 
i have change the code at line 59 from

strLink = "../" & "RequisitionForm.asp?Cancel=Yes&DocketID=" & arrDockets(0, i) & "&Code=" & arrDockets(4, i)



to


strLink = "../" & "RequisitionForm.asp?DocketID=" & arrDockets(0, i) & "&Code=" & arrDockets(4, i)


What was the effect of the change. I dont know what happens if i make this changes.

Comment: it loads the page RequisitionForm.asp without the parameter Cancel with value Yes, so look in that page and for this parametere and what is does to see the difference

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the table by recreating a new page.
I have changed the code at line 59 from:

```
strLink = "../" & "RequisitionForm.asp?Cancel=Yes&DocketID=" & arrDockets(0, i) & "&Code=" & arrDockets(4, i)
```

to

```
strLink = "../" & "RequisitionForm.asp?DocketID=" & arrDockets(0, i) & "&Code=" & arrDockets(4, i)
```

I have removed `Cancel=yes`
What was the effect of the change? I don't know what happens if I make these changes.